# Google maps set only the selected marker draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to drag only the selected marker on google maps, i'am now using this code:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
        this.setDraggable(true);
    });
```

But now, when you click on another marker, the previous selected marker is also draggable.

Kind regards,
Gjjansen

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. You say you want to remove a marker. The code you posted sets an event listener on a marker. And what is a "selected" marker for you?

Comment: Excuse me, i mean: "is it possible to drag only the selected marker". Not remove it. A selected marker for me is the marker you clicked on before the one you select now. Hope it's a bit clear!

Comment: You need to keep references to all the markers and set all the _other_ markers to draggable: false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable or a map-property to store a reference to the clicked marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  

    var map        = this.getMap(),
        dragMarker = map.get('dragMarker');

    if(dragMarker){
       dragMarker.setDraggable(false);
    }
    this.setDraggable(true);
    map.set('dragMarker', this)
});
```

Comment: I'll try that asap, and i'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

the poly-line or polygon will move with draggable marker
here is the code, implement draggable marker listener and its methods

```
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {


    if(distanceclick){

        int listsize = points.size();
        points.remove(listsize-1);
        if(polyline != null) polyline.remove();
        points.add(marker.getPosition());
        drawployline(points);
    }
    if(areaclick){

        int listsize = points.size();
        points.remove(listsize-1);
        if(polygon != null) polygon.remove();
        points.add(marker.getPosition());
        drawploygon(points);


    }



}



//here is the function to draw polygone/ polyline
    private void drawploygon(List<LatLng> points) {

    if(polygon != null) polygon.remove();

    PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().addAll(points)
            .clickable(true);
    polygon = mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
    polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.RED);
    polygon.setStrokeWidth(3f);
    polygon.setFillColor(Color.CYAN);
}
//polyline
  private void drawployline(List<LatLng> points) {
    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polylineOptions.color(Color.CYAN);
    polylineOptions.width((float) 2.0);
    polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
    polyline.setPoints(points);
}
```